# Assigning a variable to a global environment in the function doesn't work R

Tags: r

So I created a function so it is easier to update multiple variables in the dataframe. It looks like this:

```
preprocessing <- function(variable){
  # remove punctuation
  variable <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", variable)

  #Remove stopwords
  variable <- removeWords(variable, stopwords("en"))

  #Remove certain words
  variable <- gsub(" x ", "", variable)
  variable <- gsub("ft", "", variable)
  variable <<- variable
}

preprocessing(myData$product_title)`
```

By changing variable(the one before the <<-) to e.g. myData(the dataframe) will work, but that overrides my whole dataframe and that's not what I want.

I also thought using assign:

```
assign(variable, variable, .globalEnv)
```

But of course, the first value needs to be a string, so this doesn't work.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: `<<-` will look up the parent environments for `variable` and assign to it. The problem is that if it is not deliberately initialized beforehand, it can be hard to control in which environment it ends up. The better way to do this would be to simply return `variable` from the function and assign the results: `variable <- preprocessing(myData$product_title)`

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation！